# How do I automate text display from a .json file based on the current date?

Tags: java, android, json

My team is trying to build a basic app that displays different text depending on what day of the year it is. The information that needs to be displayed is currently in the form of .json files, but any solution (involving manually inputting the data) would work for our purposes. We have three different tabs in our app that display the text for today, tomorrow, and for the week as a whole. Currently the string variables in  the string.xml are hard coded, and used in the tab_fragment.xml to provide a text output to the different tabs. How can I use Android Studio to automate the displayed text depending on the date?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `SimpleDateFormat`. You pass in a `Date` object, and it can format it into the correct text, such as `Friday`.

```
Date now = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("E"); // the day of the week abbreviated
System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(now));

simpleDateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); // the day of the week spelled out completely
System.out.println(simpleDateformat.format(now));
```

`new Date()` will return the current date of the device. If you want to display other days, you need to create multiple `Date` objects.